# How to Add a Column if the Date is in a specific month on ongoing basis

Tags: excel, sumifs

Table "Giveaways" is an ongoing list of items that I want to summarize each month in another tab. I've looked at other questions for this but keep coming up with an error; the result shows up in mnoth.

Tried this thread at no avail "Excel Formula to SUMIF date falls in particular month" can someone please help?

[image]

I want the total quantity (column b) for each month where the date is listed in column c indefinitely.

Thanks a million!!

Answer (score 1):

`SUMIF` or `SUMIFS` are magic but not always the (best) solution because the syntax of the criteria is annoyingly limited. `SUMPRODUCT` is more flexible. To sum for a month, say 6 (June):

```
 =SUMPRODUCT($B2:$B100 * (MONTH($C2:$C100)=6))
```

You can replace `6` by any month number or any cell reference such as `E1`. If the referenced cell contains a date and you want to match the same month, replace `6` by `MONTH(E1)`.